# Right align and vertically middle subtext in Bootstrap dropdown menu item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to have a small caption on the right hand-side of a dropdown menu, for each item, vertically aligned with the item's text. In the example, the captions/sub-text are the numbers.

[image]

123, and 12345 are floating to the top of their respective lines. 1234567 has undesirably wrapped to a new line

I am able to get this to work with a simple, non-bootstrap version, but introducing Bootstrap is causing problems. I haven't entered the code into jsfiddle or the SO-provided web code utilities, as they seem to stretch the example width to fill the window which masks the problem. Here's the code:

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.ih {
    font-size: 85%;
    float: right;
}
.name {
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown open">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="a">
<li>
<a href="#">
<div class="name">blah blah</div>
<div class="ih">123</div>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">
<div class="name">short</div>
<div class="ih">12345</div>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">
<div class="name">really really really long</div>
<div class="ih">1234567</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: sounds logical to me... you have 2 elements on the same line, if the first is too long, then the second goes to the next line...

Comment: It's supposed to expand to fit the contents. It normally does until floats get involved. Without Bootstrap it works as expected.

Comment: it's "dropdown style" related... Bootstrap defines some properties for .dropdown class. To test it, just add a fixed width to your .dropdown item...

Comment: Setting your items with "float" property make them "non-influent" on the container width.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Bootstrap, then it would be better to use Bootstrap artifacts (CSS and Components) rather than fight it with your own layout. Then customize your styles on top of the Bootstrap's. It will be easier to maintain the code then.

In order to do what you want, easiest solution would be to just treat your *dropdown* as a *list-group*. Add the `list-group` class to your `dropdown-menu` and also make it a `div` instead of `ul`. Then it is just a matter of marking your `a` with `list-group-item` class and `pull-right` on the numbers.

In the example fiddle below, just drag the splitter to increase/decrease the size of the result pane to see how it behaves in all media-query widths. For the example snippet, just view it full-screen.

***Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1o5o29jy/***

***Snippet***:

```css
.dropdown-menu { padding: 0px; }
.dropdown-menu, .list-group { border-width: 0px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                    Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu list-group">
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                        <span class="pull-right">123</span>
                        <span>Caption</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                        <span class="pull-right">12345</span>
                        <span>Description</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
                        <span class="pull-right">99</span>
                        <span>Very long description</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue seen here is because there is no more space for it to render in the same line.

There are two ways to do get a solution for this.

**Option 1#**
Add extra width to the `.navbar-nav` class to incorporate the extra text. But since you need it to be dynamic, I suggest you to try the below trick shown in option 2.

**Option 2#**
Add the same text in the `.name` class and make `opacity:0;`.
And, instead of float right for `.ih` class, do a `position: absolute; right: 0; top:6px;` on it and add the following css.

Below is what the code would be like.

```css
.dropdown-menu li a {
    position:relative;
}
.ih {
    font-size: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top:6px;
}
.ih-dummy { /* this is a new class */
    margin-left:15px;
    font-size: 85%;
    opacity:0;    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav trial">
    <li class="dropdown open">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="a">
            <li> <a href="#">
            <div class="name">blah blah<span class="ih-dummy">123</span></div>
            <div class="ih">123</div>
          </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
            <div class="name">short<span class="ih-dummy">12345</span></div>
            <div class="ih">12345</div>
          </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
            <div class="name">really really really long<span class="ih-dummy">1234567</span></div>
            <div class="ih">1234567</div>
          </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```